# How to ensure CSV file is not blank in ASP Classic before opening?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am having an issue with very large CSV files not yet being created when opening them in ASP Classic. The code is below.

```
csvFile.close()
Set csvFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileFullPath = fso.BuildPath(xRefCsvRoot, filename)
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strFileFullPath, 1)

strFile = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close()

response.Clear()
response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename
response.Write(strFile)
response.End()
```

Is there an effective way to just check that the file is not blank before reading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [file size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d66skaf.aspx):

```
If fso.GetFile(strFileFullPath).Size > 0 Then
  'file is not empty
End If
```